# Symfony2 unserialize to Create doctrine Entity with DateTime using serializer

Tags: json, symfony, datetime, serialization, doctrine

I have a doctrine entity containing DateTime fields.
When I serialize the object to be used by forms, I transform datetime objects using this callback function (taken from symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)):

```
$callback = function ($dateTime) {
    return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
        ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::ISO8601)
        : '';
```

this function is attached to the normalizer.

The date is further transformed to a string using `dd/MM/yyyy` picture and placed to a form as a string (I am using a JavaScript datepicker).

The form is posted using ajax to a controller that gets the entity as a PHP array.

Now I need to transform the array (containing tha date as a string) back to my Doctrine entity.

Is there a way to deserialize an array to an Entity?
I tried to `deserialize(json_encode($array))` but I get error on DateTime conversion.

any hint?

Comment: Did you try a Data Transformer in your form? (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most recommand way to do something like that is using the Symfony2 DateTime FormType

Could look like that:

```
        $builder->add(
            'date',
            'datetime',
            array(
                'widget'   => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'
            )
        );
```

If you don't like use Form Component, I dont know an easy way to map an array to an entity.